# Button Error eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

I am trying to write a simple little programm now. I'm new to android and programming in general. I would like to get to the new screen by clicking on the button.Here's what I have:

```
package savin.test1;

import savin.test1.button1click;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, button1click.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

However, when I launch the app in emulator and click on the button, the app shuts down. What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

My LogCat:

```
03-01 00:51:17.066: D/libEGL(25657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-01 00:51:17.076: D/libEGL(25657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-01 00:51:17.086: D/libEGL(25657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): Remote Branch: 
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): Local Patches: 
03-01 00:51:17.086: I/Adreno200-EGL(25657): Reconstruct Branch: 
03-01 00:51:17.396: D/OpenGLRenderer(25657): Enabling debug mode 0
03-01 00:51:20.339: D/GestureDetector(25657): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-01 00:51:20.379: D/AndroidRuntime(25657): Shutting down VM
03-01 00:51:20.379: W/dalvikvm(25657): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c81ac8)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {savin.test1/savin.test1.button1click}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at savin.test1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17962)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-01 00:51:20.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25657):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoCorrect"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="button1Click"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="@string/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="@string/button6" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I forgot to declare activity in AndroidManifest.xml - that was the problem. Now everything works perfectly fine. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Post your LogCat please (if you use Eclipse: Window > Show View > Other... > LogCat).

Comment: Please post your Activity's XML as well. I suspect there may be an issue with the `button1` ID.

Comment: Apps never (or rarely) just shut down... There should always be a stacktrace, that shows the errors, that is if you are connected as a debugging device.

Comment: > have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {savin.test1/savin.test1.button1click}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` is your error. Check @Senna's answer to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! the problem was that i Hadn't declared activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Now it's working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you don't have the activity "button1click". Create an activity and try again. You can see instructions [here](http://www.javabeat.net/create-new-activity-android/).

At the end, it will look like the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashboardActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly creating an `onClickListener` but in the XML for `button1` you are telling Android to invoke the method `button1Click()`, yet you are not providing that method.

I suggest you change this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="button1Click"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
```

to this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
```

Note: I have removed `android:onClick="button1Click"`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the logcat is

> Unable to find explicit activity class {savin.test1/savin.test1.button1click}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

If you have a class named `button1click` which extends `Activity`, then you need to declare it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For more details, you should look at [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

p.s. You should either use `setOnClickListener()` in your Java code or the `onClick` attribute in your XML layout file, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have `button1click` activity or not

Intents was used to communicate between Android components:

**Example**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```